# What this number means: $\bar{2}.767$

Tags: notation, logarithms

I faced this situation when I was solving this problem:

$\log(x) = 1.233 \Rightarrow  colog (x) = ?$

The right answer was:

$\bar{2}.767$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With logarithms one sometimes uses a notation where the fractional part of a decimal number always counts *positively*.

With this notation $\overline 2.767$ means $(-2)+0.767$ or in other words $-1.233$.

This is useful especially when working with *logarithm tables* (which essentially nobody does nowadays when we all have pocket computers) because $10^{\overline 2.767} = 10^{-2}\cdot 10^{0.767}$ -- you can look up $10^{0.767}$ in a logarithm table and then just move the point to account for the integer part of the logarithm.

In contrast, to use $10^{-1.233}$ directly you would need to do $10^{-1}/10^{0.233}$, which would need a long division by the number you get from the logarithm table, and negate the practical point of using logarithms in the first place.

Comment: Fantastic answer with a good historical reasoning. Love it!

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
-1.233 &= -1 -0.233\\
&=-2+1-0.233\\
&=-2+0.767\\
&=\bar{2}.767
\end{align}

That is the meaning of the bar:  $-2 + 0.767$.